# AngularJS Function Scope Syntax Issue

Tags: angularjs

We're going through some code and found a function call like this:

```
functionName({objectName});
```

I cannot for the life of me find documentation about that syntax and why/when it's necessary. I think it had something to do with passing data from child to parent component or something.

Any help understanding when this syntax is needed, would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is shorthand for

```
function(param) {
  const objectName = param.objectName;
}
```

it is called destructuring.

If you have an object

`const obj = { prop1: 1, prop2: 2 };`

you can assign the properties to variables like

`const { prop1, prop2 } = obj;`

Now you have `prop1` that equals 1 and `prop2` that equals 2.

So calling a function `func(obj)` where the definition is `function func({ prop1 }) { return prop1 * 2; }` the function gets prop1 from obj and would return 2.

Comment: Thanks, but is there a time in ng when that is required. I feel like it's required when doing something with directives but I can't find where I had read it previously.

Comment: It has nothing to do with Angular, it is a JavaScript concept.

Answer (score -1):

This is es6 syntax.

```
functionName({objectName});
```

is short for

```
functionName({objectName: objectName});
```

Comment: I downvoted this thinking the answer was destructuring but realise this might be the case if you are creating an object to pass in as a parameter for calling the function. I can't remove the downvote as it says my vote is locked unless the post is edited.